# SPARQL query to find invalid date in Wikidata

Tags: wikidata, sparql

The following wikidata query lists the teams Cristiano Ronaldo played for including start and end dates.

```
SELECT ?playerLabel ?teamLabel ?start ?end WHERE {
  VALUES ?player {
    wd:Q11571
  }
  ?player p:P54 ?teams.
  ?teams ps:P54 ?team;
    pq:P580 ?start.
  OPTIONAL { ?teams pq:P582 ?end. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

[Link to query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FplayerLabel%20%3FteamLabel%20%3Fstart%20%3Fend%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fplayer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ11571%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fplayer%20p%3AP54%20%3Fteams.%0A%20%20%3Fteams%20ps%3AP54%20%3Fteam%3B%0A%20%20%20%20pq%3AP580%20%3Fstart.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fteams%20pq%3AP582%20%3Fend.%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

His end date at Juventus is not a valid date.

*Partial Result*

| playerLabel | teamLabel | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Juventus F.C. | 10 July 2018 | t2136841315 |

**Question:** What is the correct way to show items with invalid dates?

Comment: Actually, invalid dates are present on Wikidata, but these `t`s are blank node labels. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44111025, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374813.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks! `isBlank` is what I'm looking for. Your StackOverflow links turned the light on in my head.

Answer (score 2):

you could  add this line:     `BIND( STR(?end)  as ?ended ).`

```
SELECT  ?playerLabel ?teamLabel ?start ?ended  WHERE {
  VALUES ?player {
    wd:Q11571
  }
  ?player p:P54 ?teams.
  ?teams ps:P54 ?team;
    pq:P580 ?start.
  OPTIONAL { 
    ?teams pq:P582 ?end. 
   
    BIND( STR(?end)  as ?ended ).
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

This will result in [this](https://w.wiki/sQq). The  dates are now longer but still in ISO8601 format.

| **playerLabel** | **teamLabel** | **start** | **ended** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Portugal national under-15 football team | 2001-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2001-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Portugal national under-17 football team | 2001-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2002-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Sporting CP | 2002-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2003-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Portugal national under-21 football team | 2002-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2003-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Portugal national association football team | 2003-01-01T00:00:00Z |  |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Portugal national under-20 football team | 2003-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2003-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Manchester United F.C. | 2003-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2009-07-01T00:00:00Z |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Portugal Olympic football team | 2004-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2004-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Real Madrid CF | 2009-07-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-10T00:00:00Z |
| Cristiano Ronaldo | Juventus F.C. | 2018-07-10T00:00:00Z |  |

Comment: That is good to know. That field doesn't convert to string. Is there a way to filter on that `null` value? I'm looking for errors in the data.